# How to bind SWT objects to the center of the application window?

Tags: swt

I am using SWT to create an application GUI, and I don't really need to resize the components, but it does bother me that when the window is maximized, the components stay left-aligned. Is there a way to fix this with SWT or do I need to utilize a different set of GUI tools?

Thanks in advance. I am using SWT 4.8 for this application.

EDIT: Images

Small: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zVNeY.jpg

Maximized: https://i.stack.imgur.com/03Lii.jpg

Provided images are a basic application using the following code

```java
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Text;
import org.eclipse.swt.SWT;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Button;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite;

public class TestWindow {

    protected Shell shlSwtApplicationExample;
    private Text text;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            TestWindow window = new TestWindow();
            window.open();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Open the window.
     */
    public void open() {
        Display display = Display.getDefault();
        createContents();
        shlSwtApplicationExample.open();
        shlSwtApplicationExample.layout();
        while (!shlSwtApplicationExample.isDisposed()) {
            if (!display.readAndDispatch()) {
                display.sleep();
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Create contents of the window.
     */
    protected void createContents() {
        shlSwtApplicationExample = new Shell();
        shlSwtApplicationExample.setSize(705, 529);
        shlSwtApplicationExample.setText("SWT Application Example");

        Composite composite = new Composite(shlSwtApplicationExample, SWT.NONE);
        composite.setBounds(10, 10, 669, 465);

        text = new Text(composite, SWT.BORDER);
        text.setBounds(22, 10, 334, 295);

        Button btnNewButton = new Button(composite, SWT.NONE);
        btnNewButton.setBounds(49, 384, 137, 26);
        btnNewButton.setText("New Button");

        Button button = new Button(composite, SWT.NONE);
        button.setText("New Button");
        button.setBounds(300, 384, 137, 26);

    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show a screenshot? Makes it easier to assess.

Comment: What Layout are you using or are you using `setBounds`?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that we can help troubleshoot.

Comment: I will do my best, I can't add images directly since I am new. Edit posted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using `setBounds` you will need to add a Control listener to the shell to be told about resize and move events. You will then have to recalculate the positions on each resize event.

```java
shlSwtApplicationExample.addControlListener(
    new ControlListener() {
        @Override
        public void controlMoved(ControlEvent event) {
            // No action
        }

        @Override
        public void controlResized(ControlEvent event) {
           Rectangle rect = shlSwtApplicationExample.getClientArea();

           // TODO Call new `setBounds` on each control based on the 
           // client area size
        }
    });
```

This might be a good time to learn about using Layouts instead of `setBounds` (see  [here](https://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-Understanding-Layouts/Understanding-Layouts.htm)). Layouts will automatically deal with resizes.

Comment: I had an issue implementing the layouts you have provided, but the tip to use the control listener was what I needed! For whatever reason, composites were having an issue conforming to the shapes generated by some of the layouts. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 3):

I would not recommend using setBounds since it does not resize the components when you resize the application. Use Layouts, like for example below I have used GridLayout for both the `Shell` and the `Composite` which will properly arrange the UI when resize happens.

```
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Text;
import org.eclipse.swt.SWT;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.GridData;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.GridLayout;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Button;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite;

public class TestWindow {

    protected Shell shlSwtApplicationExample;
    private Text text;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            TestWindow window = new TestWindow();
            window.open();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Open the window.
     */
    public void open() {
        Display display = Display.getDefault();
        createContents(display);
        shlSwtApplicationExample.open();
        shlSwtApplicationExample.layout();
        shlSwtApplicationExample.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, false));
        while (!shlSwtApplicationExample.isDisposed()) {
            if (!display.readAndDispatch()) {
                display.sleep();
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Create contents of the window.
     * @param display 
     */
    protected void createContents(Display display) {
        shlSwtApplicationExample = new Shell(display);
        shlSwtApplicationExample.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, false));

        Composite txtcomposite = new Composite(shlSwtApplicationExample, SWT.NONE);
        txtcomposite.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, false));
        txtcomposite.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true));

        Composite btncomposite = new Composite(shlSwtApplicationExample, SWT.NONE);
        btncomposite.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, false));
        btncomposite.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, false));

        text = new Text(txtcomposite, SWT.BORDER);
        text.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true));

        Button btnNewButton = new Button(btncomposite, SWT.NONE);
        btnNewButton.setText("New Button");

        Button button = new Button(btncomposite, SWT.NONE);
        button.setText("New Button");

        shlSwtApplicationExample.setText("SWT Application Example");
        //shlSwtApplicationExample.setSize(705, 529);

    }
}
```

Comment: I honestly wanted to use layouts, but the problem with composites that I have seen (perhaps its a problem in my project setup) is that I can't set the backgrounds to what I need. They just stay that slightly off-white color. Thank you for your help on this problem though!

Comment: @Sam "They just stay that slightly off-white color." - You should definitely be able to change the background color, so it sounds like there's something not quite right in your code. If you're still having issues, consider posting a new question and we can try to help.